# cordova facebook function login() , how can i apply for both login and registration purpose

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, twitter

I am stuck on app registration with facebook,
1] I have integrated with facebook and i want to register with same function login() as i did with login with facebook , so in HTML page i am calling same function but different purpose in registration i want to register with facebook + after that it should go manual form of app register and in that form some field that i want to fetch should be in the form , then i should go form main page.

```
       var login = function () {
            if (!window.cordova) {
                var appId = prompt("Enter FB Application ID", "");
                facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
            }
            facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"],reg());
                // function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
                // function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
            }

        var showDialog = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog( { method: "feed" }, 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }

        var apiTest = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me?fields=id,name,email",
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }); 
        }

        var getAccessToken = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken( 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }

        var getStatus = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus( 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }

        var logout = function () { 
            alert(1);
            facebookConnectPlugin.logout( 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to include the facebook plugin https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257
- Make sure to include "Cordova"

Sample working code

```
 $("#facebookLogin").click(function () {
                if (!window.cordova) {
                    facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(YOURAPPID);
                }
                facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email","public_profile","user_friends"], 
                    function (response) {

                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      facebookConnectPlugin.api('me/?fields=id,name,email,picture', {},function(response) {
    //handle the response usually pass it to PHP using ajax to login process
    });
    }           });});
```